# WebService french characters got replaced by question marks

Tags: vb.net, web-services, encoding, utf-8, postman

I have a web service designed in VB.NET. TextEncoding in the Web.Service specifies UTF-8 in the BasicHttpBinding section.

When I consume the WebMethod from the Web Service from a .NET test application I made, it works fine.

If I test the WebSerivce using Postman, all the special french accentued characters are replaced by question marks (??).

[image]

WebMethod "InsertIntoPak" has a single parameter (xmlData) which is a string type. This method log the content of the xmlData string into a flat file then insert it into a SQL database.

Both, the file and the database shows question mark instead of the accentued characters passed as a parameter.

What are we doing wrong? Any idea?

Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: The idea is that you're using the wrong encoding somewhere. Writing to the file? What encoding is used for this? Is the source file actually UFT-8 encoded? Or it's just a header string that says that?

Comment: thanks for your reply. We finally could fix this problem by switching to soap 1.2 request. Odd, but it works now!